# LaTeXit error message 34304

Tags: errors, latexit

I run LaTeXit and get this message (I cannot export):

```
An error occured while trying to create the file with command:
/usr/local/bin/gs-noX11 -sstdout=(null)tderr -sDEVICE=eps2write -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=- -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -dNOPLATFONTS -dNoOutputFonts=true /var/folders/ww/ylm3bybx3pnd35_blrww9y1c0000gq/T/LaTeXiT-2.8.1/latexit-controller-0x6000002bc020.pdf -c quit 2>|/var/folders/ww/ylm3bybx3pnd35_blrww9y1c0000gq/T/LaTeXiT-2.8.1/export.eI2SEDMO.log | /usr/local/bin/ps2pdf  -dSubsetFonts=false -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=100000 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=100000 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress  - /var/folders/ww/ylm3bybx3pnd35_blrww9y1c0000gq/T/LaTeXiT-2.8.1/latexit-controller-0x6000002bc020-2.pdf 1>>/var/folders/ww/ylm3bybx3pnd35_blrww9y1c0000gq/T/LaTeXiT-2.8.1/export.eI2SEDMO.log 2>&1.
```

When I ask to see the error message I get:

```
Error 34304:
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gs
  Reason: image not found
```

I reinstall the program with no change

Comment: Please update to the latest version of LaTeXiT.

Comment: Herb, I did. No change.

Comment: what version are you using. For a short time there was a version that had some bad dynamic linking.

Comment: Sorry Herb, I let some time slip. Reinstalled LateXit Version 2.16.2 (2.16.2). Still get the message: An error occured while trying to create the file with command:
Error 34304:
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gs
  Reason: image not found

Comment: What version of ghostscript are you using? What macOS version are you using? If you are using Big Sur do you have XQuartz installed? If you believe so, what version is it? You need 2.8.1 for Big Sur and then re-install Ghostscript. Finally, what output are you trying to export to?

Comment: Not sure about ghostscript. I looked for it and found two folders: 8.62 and 9.21. Not sure I am using Big Sur. Don't have XQuartz installed. MacBook Pro 2013 Catalina 10.15.7. I am exporting to Illustrator, as I have always done. Thanks

Comment: In Terminal run `gs --version` to get the ghostscript version.

Comment: In the Typesetting tab of LaTeXiT->Preferences what do you have in the Ghostscript and ps2pdf sections?  They should be `/usr/local/bin/gs` and `/usr/local/bin/ps2pdf` respectively. If those are correct you may have to reset a symbolic link since gs-noX11 shouldn't be looking for X11 libraries. Let me know and I'll give you instructions.